# Descargar archivo desde REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, archivo, rest

Buenas tardes, espero estén teniendo un buen día y me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema....

Tengo el siguiente recurso:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dowload", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadPDFFile()
        throws IOException {

    File file = new File("/home/recursos/archivos.pdf");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(resource);
}
```

Lo intento acceder de la siguiente forma

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);


            ResponseEntity<Resource> response = clientAccess.exchange("http://localhost:8081/springjwt/dowload", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error

```
  Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1b318862; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1b318862; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Uso Spring Boot para implementar el servidor REST.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el error persiste. Añado otra parte del codigo que me parece es importante y posiblemente este configurando mal algo.

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate clientAccess(String user, String password) {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setUsername(user);
    resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8081/oauth/token");
    resourceDetails.setClientId("testjwtclientid");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("XY7kmzoNzl100");
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
    resourceDetails.setScope(asList("read", "write"));

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

    System.out.println(restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue());

    //final Object greeting = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/springjwt/cities", Object.class);
    System.out.println("");
    //System.out.println(greeting);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Lo que me regresa como respuesta lo utilizo para realizar las posteriores peticiones, realizo una primera para obtener los datos del usuario y la realiza correctamente, ya cuando intento descargar el archivo es cuando obtengo el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo la nueva información que has subido, te puedo decir que el error se encuentra en tu método clientAccess. Le estas indicando a jackson que el converter `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` que se usa para escribir y leer JSON, Lo use para trabajar con bytes que es lo que devuelve `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE`.

Te agrego el metodo con el cambio realizado.

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate clientAccess(String user, String password) {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setUsername(user);
    resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8081/oauth/token");
    resourceDetails.setClientId("testjwtclientid");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("XY7kmzoNzl100");
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
    resourceDetails.setScope(asList("read", "write"));

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    //MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    //mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    //converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    //converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    //converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
    //converters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    //converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);
    System.out.println(restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue());

    //final Object greeting = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/springjwt/cities", Object.class);
    System.out.println("");
    //System.out.println(greeting);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Si te fijas bien, solo dejé un converter que es el correcto para lo que devuelve tu servicio, sinembargo por defecto Spring configurar todos los otros converters que estan comentados en el código, osea que si tu no agregas ningún converter jackson ya los deberia tener agregados: El metodo `restTemplate.getMessageConverters()` te muestra todos los converters ya agregados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, he utilizado el código que me proporcionaste pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error. Actualiza la pregunta donde  indico la manera en que configuro, espero me puedas seguir ayudando y perdón por haber tardado en revisar.

Comment: Hola, No te entiendo bien la pregunta. Has una buena formulación y posteala. No olvides votar por la respuesta por favor s una buena forma de agradecer.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente sin modificar los convertes funciona perfectamente. Si no es mucha molestia solo me podrías ayudar a entender la diferencia entre usar los que ya estan agregados y usar MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, si no es mucha molestia por favor.

Comment: Perdón elimine la pregunta creo que si no fue muy clara. Todo bien con tu explicación. Gracias de nuevo.}

Comment: Es con mucho gusto Kote, no olvides votar por la pregunta es un buen gesto.